# return value from servlet and let execution in background

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
WhoopieeMerchantAppContactGroupModel group_model = new WhoopieeMerchantAppContactGroupModel();
        boolean result = group_model.checkGroupName(groupName);
        if(result)
        {
            writer.write("true");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.write("error");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }

        System.out.println("here sirji");

        group_model.createGroup(groupName, dto_list, store_id);
        System.out.println("here sirji at the end");
```

this is my code, i want when the writer sends the true or error result, then the create group function call will execute in background. But it shows processing till the creategroup function is not finishing its execution. is there a way in which i can exit from that servlet and let the execution in the background

Comment: you must study how to work with Threads in Java. here you are some clue http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear but look into Asynchronous Processing in servlets